# Scale works weird with custom orientation

Tags: transforms, transform-orientation

If i move an object using a custom transform orientation axis, everything works correctly. But scale works wrong, scale to 0 using custom X axis can't make object flat. And i can't scale the arm on screenshot correctly. Scale with custom orientation not possible?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scaling in object mode only affects object-level transformations. Scaling the same object in edit mode will work as expected.
If you look at the object after scaling it in edit mode it should become clear that the same transformation would have been impossible to achieve with just rotation and scale.
[image: editmode]

One way to do it in object mode is to align the object's origin along the intended orientation.
[image: origin]
You can do this without an extra object, by simply rotating the origin point.

If rotating the origin is impossible (e.g. due to armature or constraints), you can instead use a Lattice.
[image: lattice]
Mesh Deform / Surface Deform modifiers could help with trickier cases, the idea is similar to Lattice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very detailed explanation! And for showing other ways to do it. This is very helpful!!!